# Data Recovery from Tru64 Unix

Tags: unix, data-recovery, tru64

I accidently deleted a directory in Tru64 unix Server. Is it possible to retrieve back the directory.. It contained many other directories and Anyhow I need to retrieve the data as it was a very important directory..

Kindly let me know the process or some good website which details about the particular scenario..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you are out of luck.  Tru64 uses a filesystem called ADVfs which does have support for undelete/trashcan (I think this is a licensed feature though so you may not have it installed, in which case you are out of luck). See the links below:

http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40G_HTML/SUPPDOCS/ADVFSADM/DOCU_004.HTM#TofC60
http://www.phys.uu.nl/DU/Tru64_5.0/HTML/ARH96ATE/CHPTRNXX.HTM

ADVfs also supports snapshots so you could see if there are any in existence.   Other than that it's a restore from backup or engage someone with ADVfs skills to try and recover it.

Comment: Hi Please go through the following link... Does these will work in tru64??


http://www.ehow.com/how_5202235_retrieve-deleted-files-linux.html

http://www.ehow.com/how_2064953_recover-deleted-files-linux.html

Comment: Now I'm no Unix expert by any means, but reading through those looks like it will be hassle not only for yourself, but others using the system too. It seems to me that restoring from backup would be the simplest option and wouldn't result in any disruption either.

Comment: Hello Sir.. 
   I tried this trashcan command. It worked only for files.. i.e. if there are directories inside a directoryy and so on... Then these directories doesn't goes to trashcan directoryy.. Any solution for the samee...